# Javascript Regex match a line that ends with char ' when not preceeded by?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will match all lines with certain PREFIX and the match should end when a char `'` is found.
However, if there is a `?` before the `'`, then it should not count it as the end of the line.
Basically the question mark `?` serves as a escape char.

This is what I have been using, but it does not work for what i'm trying to do:
This is the regex `/SOME_PREFIX+[^']+/`

[EDIT]
This is the full expected text:

`you could have something before'SOME_PREFIX foo bar'something in the middle'SOME_PREFIX BAR FOO ?'SHOULD ALSO MATCH'test'`

`SOME_PREFIX foo bar'` <---Should be a match 1

`SOME_PREFIX BAR FOO ?'SHOULD ALSO MATCH'` <--- Should be a match 2, but this line does not work, since it only matches up until `?'` which is the first ocurrence of the `'`

For reference: https://regexr.com/63io9

Comment: Are you trying to find several matches in a multiline text? Or are you looking for one match in one line?

Comment: @MikeM yes, several matches, but not a multiline. Should be a single string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use, for example:

```js
const text = "you could have something before'SOME_PREFIX foo bar'something in the middle'SOME_PREFIX BAR FOO ?'SHOULD ALSO MATCH'test'";

const matches = text.match(/SOME_PREFIX(?:[^'?]+|\?'?)*'/g);

console.log(matches);
```

`[^'?]+` matches any character that is not a `'` or `?`, one or more times, and `\?'?` means match a `?` optionally follwed by a `'`.

An alternation construct such as `(?:x|y)` means try and match `x` first and if it doesn't match, then try and match `y`.

Comment: This one worked. Thanks for the help, I have been looking for this for like 4 hours today. Is it possible to exclude the end of line? exclude the last `'` when the line ends

Comment: @Isanz You can just add `?` to make the `'` at the end of the regex optional, i.e `'?`, so that it match up to the end of the line - if that is what you mean. If it is not, please clarify.

Comment: Yeah, I just needed to remove the `'` at the end of your regex to not include that.
Something like this: `/SOME_PREFIX(?:[^'?]+|\?'?)*/g`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?!.*\?'$)SOME_PREFIX.+'
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/oHT9VJ/1/).

Comment: This wouldn't match up to the first `'` if the string was for example `SOME_PREFIX foo bar' HOW ARE YOU?'`.

Comment: Yeah, this would not quite work. Maybe I didn't add the best example. The prefix is not necessarily the beginning. and you could have some text in the middle as well and should not match that part. I've updated the demo https://regexr.com/63io9

Answer (score 1):

If a [lookbehind is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) in your environment, you could match `SOME_PREFIX`, and then match any char except SOME_PREFIX or a `'` and only match the `'` when it it directly preceded by `?`

```
SOME_PREFIX(?:(?!SOME_PREFIX|').)*(?:(?<=\?)'(?:(?!SOME_PREFIX|').)*)*'
```

**Explanation**

- `SOME_PREFIX` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `(?!SOME_PREFIX|')` Negative lookahead to assert not SOME_PREFIX or `'` directly to the right
  - `.` Match any char except a newline to not cross lines
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `(?<=\?)'` Match `'` only when directly preceded by `?`
  - `(?:(?!SOME_PREFIX|').)*` The same repeating pattern as in the first part
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `'` Match a single quote

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FCZ6MG/1)

```js
const regex = /SOME_PREFIX(?:(?!SOME_PREFIX|').)*(?:(?<=\?)'(?:(?!SOME_PREFIX|').)*)*'/g;
const str = "you could have something before'SOME_PREFIX foo bar'something in the middle'SOME_PREFIX BAR FOO ?'SHOULD ALSO MATCH'test'";
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Comment: yeah, that is what I was looking for. Thanks for your reply. I wonder if its too much overhead NOT to include the actual `'` at the end

Comment: @lsanz If you don't want to include the `'` at the end, you can omit it from the pattern.